# Fourier's trick: example of simple way of finding the Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have searched a couple of similar threads here on StackExchange but they do not provide the answer to this particular question I want to ask. It is just a simple matter of finding Fourier coefficients when they are inside a sum.

$$
\begin{equation}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\hat{u}_{k}(0)\cos(kx)=\sin(x) \end{equation}
$$

How do I obtain $\hat{u}_{k}(0)$? I know that $\cos(kx)$ has a period of $T=2\pi/k$, and if I compare to $\cos(\frac{k\pi x}{a})$ I can identify that $a=\pi$ (I remember this from a Fourier analysis course I took before). Does this mean that

$$
\hat{u}_{k}(0)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(kx)\sin(x)dx\;?
$$

If not, how do I come up with the right answer? (This was just some formula I had written down in my lecture notes long ago, alas no explanation!)

\ Best regards

Comment: To compute $\hat u_j(0)$, multiply both sides of your equation by $\cos(jx)$ and integrate over $[-\pi, \pi]$. All but one of the terms in your infinite sum will vanish. It's awesome. (You end up with the formula that you wrote.)

Comment: Thanks! You say I should integrate over $[-\pi,\pi]$ yet the result I wrote holds, how is that? The integrand is odd so your result should become zero, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions $\{\cos(kx)\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ are mutually orthogonal on $[0,\pi]$ with respect to the integral
$$
       \langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^{\pi}f(x)g(x)dx.
$$
So, if you know that
$$
         h(x) = a_0 + a_1\cos(x)+a_2\cos(2x)+\cdots,
$$
then Fourier's trick is to multiply both sides by of the functions, say $\cos(kx)$ and integrate over $[0,\pi]$ in order to obtain an explicit expression for the constants $a_k$ in terms of integrals:
$$
       \int_0^\pi h(x)\cos(kx)dx = \int_0^\pi a_k\cos^2(kx)dx \\
     a_k = \frac{\int_0^\pi h(x)\cos(kx)dx}{\int_0^{\pi}\cos^2(kx)dx}
$$